# Ubuntu 18.04 desktop freezes, mouse pointer moves, but all else is non-functional

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, usb, keyboard, mouse

I have a problem with unpredictable unresponsiveness of the system while I'm working. I can't isolate a specific cause, as it appears to be completely random, but I'll be working along, open a window or do something like click on a button in a comma-delimited file, or be working in an email, and the next thing I know is that I can't type.

The keyboard is unresponsive. <kbd>Shift lock</kbd> and <kbd>Number lock</kbd> do not work. The left and right mouse buttons don't work. The mouse cursor moves, but that's the only thing that does. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysReq</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> does nothing. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> does nothing. It's like the USB system is glitching, but it's permanent and NOTHING I do can unstick it or get it to start working again.

I've attempted to connect another USB keyboard (the normal one is a wireless Logitech keyboard and mouse that normally work well) but the second keyboard does nothing. It's like the USB system is shut down.

The ONLY way I can stop this is to hold down the power button and I lose everything. This really is not optimum. But I've seen many posts where heynnema walked through these problems and was able to pinpoint what was wrong, but I've not seen any where the tty console couldn't be conjured up and something done. This is a complete loss of the keyboard and any functionality of the machine.

Any ideas on where to start? Intel Core i7-3770CPU @ 3.4Ghz, 4 cores, 16 GB ram, Nvidia GeForce GTX 550Ti, 1 GB ram; American Megatrends 2014 Bios, Asustek Computer Motherboard P8-Z77-V.

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        5.0G        8.0G        378M        2.6G        9.9G
Swap:          2.0G          0B        2.0G
```

```
$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

```
$ sudo lshw -C memory
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 2104
       date: 08/13/2013
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 8128KiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1-Cache
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       capabilities: internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L2-Cache
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       capabilities: internal varies unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2 DISABLED
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L3-Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       capabilities: internal unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory:0 UNCLAIMED
       physical id: 1
     *-bank UNCLAIMED
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: HMT351U6EFR8C-PB
          vendor: Hynix/Hyundai
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00748856
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
  *-memory:1
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 60
       slot: System board or motherboard
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: PSD34G13332
          vendor: 8502
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: HMT351U6EFR8C-PB
          vendor: Hynix/Hyundai
          physical id: 1
          serial: 006488BC
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: PSD34G13332
          vendor: 8502
          physical id: 2
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
  *-memory:2 UNCLAIMED
       physical id: 2
  *-memory:3 UNCLAIMED
       physical id: 3
```

```
$ ls -al /var/crash
total 70636
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie     4096 Nov 14 09:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root         4096 Apr 27  2018 ..
-rw-r-----  1 greengas whoopsie 72322031 Nov 14 09:28 _opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r--  1 greengas whoopsie        0 Nov 10 22:51 _opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie        0 Nov 10 22:51 _opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.uploaded
```

```
$ dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii

ii  libnvidia-common-450-server        450.80.02-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-450-server:i386  450.80.02-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-450-server:i386   450.80.02-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-450-server:i386   450.80.02-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-450-server:i386     450.80.02-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-450-server:i386       450.80.02-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-450-server:i386     450.80.02-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  nvidia-prime                       0.8.8.2                    all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                    440.82-0ubuntu0.18.04.1    amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

Results of `/sys/log/kern.log`:

```
Nov 15 08:14:25 ReimersAsusUbuntu kernel: [ 3217.517164] audit: type=1400 audit(1605395665.728:289): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" name="/proc/11832/attr/current" pid=9515 comm="gnome-system-mo" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Nov 15 08:14:46 ReimersAsusUbuntu kernel: [ 3238.521305] audit: type=1400 audit(1605395686.732:290): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" name="/proc/11907/attr/current" pid=9515 comm="gnome-system-mo" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Nov 15 08:16:37 ReimersAsusUbuntu kernel: [ 3349.549809] audit: type=1400 audit(1605395797.760:291): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" name="/proc/12011/attr/current" pid=9515 comm="gnome-system-mo" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
Nov 15 08:17:31 ReimersAsusUbuntu kernel: [ 3403.553539] audit: type=1400 audit(1605395851.764:292): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" name="/proc/12210/attr/current" pid=9515 comm="gnome-system-mo" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
```

Seems there's some problem with OpenVPN. Results of `/var/log/sys.log`

```
Nov 15 08:28:35 ReimersAsusUbuntu systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN connection to HMA...
Nov 15 08:28:35 ReimersAsusUbuntu ovpn-HMA[13367]: Options error: In /etc/openvpn/HMA.conf:1: Error opening configuration file: /tmp/hma-config.cfg
Nov 15 08:28:35 ReimersAsusUbuntu ovpn-HMA[13367]: Use --help for more information.
Nov 15 08:28:35 ReimersAsusUbuntu systemd[1]: openvpn@HMA.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 15 08:28:35 ReimersAsusUbuntu systemd[1]: openvpn@HMA.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 15 08:28:35 ReimersAsusUbuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN connection to HMA.
Nov 15 08:28:40 ReimersAsusUbuntu systemd[1]: openvpn@HMA.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 15 08:28:40 ReimersAsusUbuntu systemd[1]: openvpn@HMA.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 773.
Nov 15 08:28:40 ReimersAsusUbuntu systemd[1]: Stopped OpenVPN connection to HMA.
Nov 15 08:28:40 ReimersAsusUbuntu systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN connection to HMA...
Nov 15 08:28:40 ReimersAsusUbuntu ovpn-HMA[13374]: Options error: In /etc/openvpn/HMA.conf:1: Error opening configuration file: /tmp/hma-config.cfg
Nov 15 08:28:40 ReimersAsusUbuntu ovpn-HMA[13374]: Use --help for more information.
Nov 15 08:28:40 ReimersAsusUbuntu systemd[1]: openvpn@HMA.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 15 08:28:40 ReimersAsusUbuntu systemd[1]: openvpn@HMA.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 15 08:28:40 ReimersAsusUbuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN connection to HMA.
Nov 15 08:28:42 ReimersAsusUbuntu org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1783]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x5600084 (*syslog (/)
```

```
$ cat /etc/openvpn/HMA.conf
config /tmp/hma-config.cfg
```

That's all that's there. I think that's a problem, but I have no idea of how to fix it. Will check on the memory slots now.

I verified there are 4 physical memory slots in the motherboard. They are each filled with a 4 GB memory module.

I have pasted the results of `cat /var/log/syslog` on [Ubuntu Pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pD38xG4q9S/)

New results of `sudo lshw -C memory` after removing both Patriot Memory PSD34G1333KH PS000830 8GB PC3-10600 1333MHz (2x4gb)Kit DIMMs and putting the two SK Hynix 4GB 2Rx8 PC3-12800U-11-13-1 DIMMs in the BLUE slots:

```
$ sudo lshw -C memory
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 2104
       date: 08/13/2013
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 8128KiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1-Cache
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       capabilities: internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L2-Cache
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       capabilities: internal varies unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2 DISABLED
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L3-Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       capabilities: internal unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory:0 UNCLAIMED
       physical id: 1
     *-bank UNCLAIMED
          description: DIMM [empty]
          product: [Empty]
          vendor: [Empty]
          physical id: 0
          serial: [Empty]
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
  *-memory:1
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 60
       slot: System board or motherboard
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
          product: HMT351U6EFR8C-PB
          vendor: Hynix/Hyundai
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00748856
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM [empty]
          product: [Empty]
          vendor: [Empty]
          physical id: 1
          serial: [Empty]
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
          product: HMT351U6EFR8C-PB
          vendor: Hynix/Hyundai
          physical id: 2
          serial: 006488BC
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
  *-memory:2 UNCLAIMED
       physical id: 2
  *-memory:3 UNCLAIMED
       physical id: 3
```

FWIW, the Patriot Memory modules were in this CPU when I purchased it. If they are the problem, then this is probably why the original owner sold it to me at a very steep discount, and he probably had problems with it.

After following heynnema's directions to remove `/etc/openVPN/HMA.conf`:

```
$ sudo rm  /etc/openvpn/HMA.conf
$ cat /etc/openvpn/HMA.conf
cat: /etc/openvpn/HMA.conf: No such file or directory
```

It is now removed.

After removing two Hynix 4GB DIMM from the blue slots and installing the two Patriot 8GB DIMMs in the black slots. The blue slots are empty.

```
$ sudo lshw -C memory 
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 2104
       date: 08/13/2013
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 8128KiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1-Cache
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       capabilities: internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L2-Cache
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       capabilities: internal varies unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2 DISABLED
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L3-Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       capabilities: internal unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory:0 UNCLAIMED
       physical id: 1
     *-bank UNCLAIMED
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: PSD34G13332
          vendor: 8502
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
  *-memory:1
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 60
       slot: System board or motherboard
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM [empty]
          product: [Empty]
          vendor: [Empty]
          physical id: 0
          serial: [Empty]
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: PSD34G13332
          vendor: 8502
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM [empty]
          product: [Empty]
          vendor: [Empty]
          physical id: 2
          serial: [Empty]
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
  *-memory:2 UNCLAIMED
       physical id: 2
  *-memory:3 UNCLAIMED
       physical id: 3
```

Below is the report with 4GB Hynix DIMMs now installed in the blue memory slots:

```
$ sudo lshw -C memory 
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 2104
       date: 08/13/2013
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 8128KiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1-Cache
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       capabilities: internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L2-Cache
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       capabilities: internal varies unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2 DISABLED
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L3-Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       capabilities: internal unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory:0 UNCLAIMED
       physical id: 1
     *-bank UNCLAIMED
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: PSD34G13332
          vendor: 8502
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
  *-memory:1
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 60
       slot: System board or motherboard
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: HMT351U6EFR8C-PB
          vendor: Hynix/Hyundai
          physical id: 0
          serial: 006488BC
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: PSD34G13332
          vendor: 8502
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: HMT351U6EFR8C-PB
          vendor: Hynix/Hyundai
          physical id: 2
          serial: 00748856
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
  *-memory:2 UNCLAIMED
       physical id: 2
  *-memory:3 UNCLAIMED
       physical id: 3
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116250/discussion-on-question-by-greengas-at-my-wits-end-ubuntu-18-04-desktop-freeze).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have various problems.

**OpenVPN**

You have lots of OpenVPN errors in /var/log/syslog. This is due to an invalid VPN .conf file. Delete it:

```
sudo rm -i /etc/openvpn/HMA.conf
```

Obtain the correct .conf file from your VPN vendor, ISP, or IT department.

**BIOS**

ASUS P8Z77-V

You have BIOS version 2104, dated 08/13/2013.

<strike>I believe that there's a newer BIOS available, but I can't check for it because there's a problem at the ASUS web site. **Call** or **Chat** with ASUS and tell them that you need to check for a new BIOS for a P8Z77-V, but that their **support** page for that motherboard is broken.</strike> See https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/P8Z77V/HelpDesk_Download/

**Note**: The ASUS web page is fixed now, and it confirms that you have the latest BIOS. Apparently you have an "Asia" motherboard, so you may have to check their overseas web pages to check if there's a newer BIOS.

**Note**: I just checked their tw web page [here](https://www.asus.com/tw/Motherboards/P8Z77V/HelpDesk_Download/), and it also shows that you have the current BIOS.

**overclocking**

Confirm that your motherboard is not overclocked, and that memory XMP is disabled. See your BIOS for these settings.

**memory**

`sudo lshw -C memory` shows a couple of problems.

```
  *-cache:2 DISABLED
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L3-Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       capabilities: internal unified
       configuration: level=3
```

L3 cache should not be DISABLED.

Also...

```
  *-memory:0 UNCLAIMED
       physical id: 1
     *-bank UNCLAIMED
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: PSD34G13332
          vendor: 8502
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
```

This should not show as UNCLAIMED.

These might be ASUS motherboard problems... but I'm hoping that a BIOS update will fix these problems.

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**Nvidia**

`dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii` shows:

```
ii  libnvidia-common-450-server        450.80.02-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-450-server:i386  450.80.02-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-450-server:i386   450.80.02-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-450-server:i386   450.80.02-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-450-server:i386     450.80.02-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-450-server:i386       450.80.02-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-450-server:i386     450.80.02-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  nvidia-prime                       0.8.8.2                    all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                    440.82-0ubuntu0.18.04.1    amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

You don't have a server, or a i386. Remove all current Nvidia softwares, obtain the correct Nvidia driver for your Nvidia GeForce GTX 550Ti, and then install it.

`sudo apt-get purge *nvidia*` # to remove old software

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be resolved. Memcheck reports all 16GB of RAM are functioning properly. Since I deleted all the NVIDIA drivers and reloaded only the correct driver for my video card, I have not had a single instance of locking up or the keyboard becoming unresponsive.

Comment: @heynnema Completed! Thank-you x 10 raised to the 8th power!